# Find Processor Type in Linux on IBM Power machine

Tags: linux, cpu, hardware

I need to find the following information of IBM Power8 running Linux:

1. Processor type
2. Model Name
3. Processor speed

Following is the required output (came from another source called BigFix) :

"IBM(R) POWER8(R) MODEL 9009-42A REV 2.1 @ 3026.000000MHZ RUNNING AS POWER8"

I have tried different commands but nothing returns such output.
Following are the commands I have tried so far :

1. dmidecode
2. lshw
3. /proc/cpuinfo
4. lscpu
5. unman -a
6. ppc64_cpu

Comment: Instead of "size", you might have meant "speed"?

Comment: yes exactly "speed". Thanks for correction.

Comment: I've [edited your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/530212/edit) to change "size" to "speed". You're also able to edit your question, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the nmon.

By opening `nmon` and then use the `r` option for `Resources Linux & Processor` will provide the information for CPU.
Note that nmon needs to be installed separately as its not out of the box utility in Linux.

**E.g:**

```
x Resources Linux & Processor 
x    Linux: Linux version 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.ppc64le (mockbuild@ppc-053.build.eng.bos.redhat.com)      
x    Build: (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) )                                      
x    Release  : 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.ppc64le                                                             
x    Version  : #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 06:58:05 UTC 2019                                                     
x    cpuinfo: cpu  : POWER8 (architected), altivec supported                                            
x    cpuinfo: clock  : 4024.000000MHz                                                                   
x    cpuinfo: revision : 2.0 (pvr 004d 0200)                                                            
x    cpuinfo: machine  : CHRP IBM,9080-MME                                                              
x    # of CPUs: 16al CPU:2 & Logical CPU:16  Little Endian                                              
x    Machine  : ppc64le                                                                                 
x    Nodename : rhel7poc                                                                                
x    /etc/*ease[1]: NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"                                              
x    /etc/*ease[2]: VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"                                                               
x    /etc/*ease[3]: ID="rhel"                                                                           
x    /etc/*ease[4]: ID_LIKE="fedora"                                                                    
x    lsb_release: not found                                                                             
x    lsb_release: (null)                                                                                
x    lsb_release: (null)                                                                                
x    lsb_release: (null)
```

Comment: nmon is actually included as part of the base OS, as of 2008: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power+Systems/page/nmon and/or https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/n_commands/nmon.html

Comment: In AIX yes but not on Linux.i had the impression that Mehdi runs Linux on Power.

Comment: Woops, I completely missed the Linux aspect; sorry!